# How to get bus/device/number from struct pci_dev?

Tags: linux, driver, pci

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pci.h#L286

In

```
struct pci_dev,
```

I can only see bus and function:

```
struct pci_bus  *bus;
```

and

```
unsigned int    devfn;
```

seems no device (of B/D/F) information?

and

```
struct pci_slot *slot;
```

In my test, the *slot point to NULL, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found:

```
device = PCI_SLOT(pdev->devfn);
fn =  PCI_FUNC(pdev->devfn);
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.5/source/include/linux/pci.h#L31

Answer (score 0):

Devfn contains the device number in bits 7:3 and the function number in bits 2:0. The bus number is in bus->number. So the BDF is

```
    bus->number << 8 | devfn
```

I don’t know about slot; perhaps the device you are looking at is an integrated device?