# What is PCI_SLOT macro?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I cannot understand what is mean slot.
It is the device number from the dbdf(Domain:bus:device:function)?

Codes from here::
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/pci.h#L32

```
/*
 * The PCI interface treats multi-function devices as independent
 * devices.  The slot/function address of each device is encoded
 * in a single byte as follows:
 *
 *  7:3 = slot
 *  2:0 = function
 */
#define PCI_DEVFN(slot, func)   ((((slot) & 0x1f) << 3) | ((func) & 0x07))
#define PCI_SLOT(devfn)     (((devfn) >> 3) & 0x1f)
#define PCI_FUNC(devfn)     ((devfn) & 0x07)
```

Comment: It's a term using for D in BDF which stands for *Bus:Device.Function*. Basically when it used to be an external PCI host bridge, the devices were connected thru physical slots (hardware connectors). In Linux this term used to avoid confusion with internal data structure called *pci_dev* and all around in the code developers refer to the instance of the `struct pci_dev` object as *PCI device*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get bus/device/number from struct pci\_dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809842/how-to-get-bus-device-number-from-struct-pci-dev)

Answer (score 0):

Each PCI peripheral is identified by a bus number, a device number, and a function
number. Each bus hosts up to 32
devices, and each device can be a multifunction board (such as an audio device with
an accompanying CD-ROM drive) with a maximum of eight functions. Therefore,
each function can be identified at hardware level by a 16-bit address, or key.

Device drivers written for Linux, though, don’t need to deal with those binary addresses,
because they use a specific data structure, called pci_dev, to act on the devices.

As the comment mentioned:

> The PCI interface treats multi-function devices as independent devices.

The independent devices in a multi-function board have the same device number, aka, PCI_SLOT(devfn), and are regarded as a physical slot, called pci_slot.

Let's dive into the code to show how the PCI peripherals are organized.

```
//in drivers/pci/probe.c
pci_scan_child_bus_extend() 

    //...
    dev_dbg(&bus->dev, "scanning bus\n");

    /* Go find them, Rover! */
    for (devfn = 0; devfn < 256; devfn += 8)
        pci_scan_slot(bus, devfn);

   //...
```

Each device can be a multifunction board with a maximum of eight functions, that is to say, a physical pci_slot hosts up to 8 independent pci_dev, so Linux scans the slot with step 8.

```
// in drivers/pci/probe.c
int pci_scan_slot(struct pci_bus *bus, int devfn)
{
    //...
    do {
        dev = pci_scan_single_device(bus, devfn + fn);
        if (dev) {
            if (!pci_dev_is_added(dev))
                nr++;
            if (fn > 0)
                dev->multifunction = 1;
        } else if (fn == 0) {
            /*
             * Function 0 is required unless we are running on
             * a hypervisor that passes through individual PCI
             * functions.
             */
            if (!hypervisor_isolated_pci_functions())
                break;
        }
        fn = next_fn(bus, dev, fn);
    } while (fn >= 0);
```

If a multifunction board has more than one functions, Linux will scan each function and allocate it a pci_dev struct. And for a non-multifunction board, only one pci_dev will be allocated.

```
pci_scan_child_bus()
    +-> pci_scan_child_bus_extend()
        +-> for (devfn = 0; devfn < 256; devfn += 8)
               pci_scan_slot()
                    +-> pci_scan_single_device()
                        +-> pci_scan_device()
                            +-> pci_bus_read_dev_vendor_id()
                            +-> pci_alloc_dev()
                            +-> pci_setup_device()
                                +-> pci_dev_assign_slot(dev);
                                    dev->slot = slot;
```

Finally, all pci_dev with the same device number in a multifunction board will link to the same pci_slot.

Reference:

1. Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition
2. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4-rc1/source/drivers/pci/probe.c#L2666